# Need Mutable varient

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, nsmutablearray

What would be the mutable varient of this line of code:

```
self.dsSearch = [self.ds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Any help appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate]` returns an `NSArray` so to make it into an `NSMutableArray` use:

```
self.dsSearch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.ds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

Or if you want an auto-released object, use:

```
self.dsSearch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.ds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

Comment: Thanks but it is giving me an ARC issue: No known class method for selector 'initWithArray:'